# If empty input text

Tags: php, csv, post

I would like to show the output"No matching records found" when empty or wrong input.
Please help me fill in the ???

```
<?

$file  = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
$output ='';
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $words = $_POST['search'];
    $words = array(preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#","",$words));

    $words = array_map('preg_quote', $words);
    // The argument becomes '/wii|guitar/i', which means 'wii or guitar, case-insensitive'
    $regex = '/'.implode('|', $words).'/i';
    if (???)
    {
        $output = "No matching records found";
    }else{
        while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
            list($name, $age, $hobbies) = $line;

            if(preg_match($regex, $hobbies)) {
                $output = "$name, $age, $hobbies<br />\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<form action="searchTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <br>
    <?php echo $output; ?>
```

```
CSV file:
name, age, hobbies
Tom, 8, "football, soccer, baseball, wii, star wars, books"
Bill, 9, "football, baseball, ice hockey, basketball"
Sue, 8, "baseball, soccer, volleyball, bicycles, skating"
Mike, 22, "basketball, music, guitar, cartoons, books"
Ella, 20, "soccer, basketball, softball, clothes, books"
Tim, 19, "football, baseball, basketball, wii, cartoons"
Steven, 18, "baseball, soccer, star wars, cartoons, books"
```

asdjkljdsfklsjklfjsdklfjsdklfsdjklfsjdklfjsdklfsd

Comment: What do you want to match?

Answer (score 1):

**You can use:**

```
if (empty($regex))
    {
        $output = "No matching records found";
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

If you entered nothing in your search box then final value of regex variable is '//i' so you have to do the following

```
$regex = '/'.implode('|', $words).'/i';

    if (empty($regex) || $regex=='//i')
    {
        $output = "No matching records found";
    }
```

Comment: If you are entering text from search and still not getting the data check you code in csv. What data you have in csv. You can attach the csv to your question

Comment: when I empty the input... its will show "No matching records found"... but when I enter a wrong input ... its show nothing...

Comment: I attach my csv already...
I mean if I type the value that not include in csv...I want its show "No matching records found"...but its show nothing...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($regex) || $regex=="")
{
    $output = "No matching records found";
}
```